# ¿Como puedo ignorar dos resultados en especifico de un query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un query que me da como resultado el inicio y fin de cada usuario, pero lo que yo quiero es poder omitir dos usuarios en especifico, ¿como puedo lograr omitir dos resultados?

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
SELECT 
    nombre, MIN(fecha) desde, MAX(fecha) hasta
FROM
    tnames
WHERE
    fecha > '2014%'
        AND nombre IN (SELECT DISTINCT
            nombre 
        FROM
            tnames 
        WHERE fecha > '2014%') GROUP BY nombre
```

Resultado:

```
-----------------------------------
nombre    |   desde    |    hasta
-----------------------------------
luis      | 2016-07-01 | 2016-08-01
marco     | 2017-01-01 | 2017-04-25
juan      | 2016-01-05 | 2016-02-20
pedro     | 2016-04-15 | 2016-01-02
mario     | 2016-03-05 | 2017-03-03
```

Como podria obtener lo siguiente que no me aparezca en mi resultado los nombres de ***Marco*** y ***Pedro***:

```
-----------------------------------
nombre    |   desde    |    hasta
-----------------------------------
luis      | 2016-07-01 | 2016-08-01
juan      | 2016-01-05 | 2016-02-20
mario     | 2016-03-05 | 2017-03-03
```

Comment: `where nombre != '%Pedro%' and nombre != '%Marco%'`

Comment: también puedes hacer un `WHERE nombre NOT IN ('marco', 'pedro')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teniendo tu `query` solo tendríamos que añadirle otra condición a nuestro `WHERE` de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT 
    nombre, MIN(fecha) desde, MAX(fecha) hasta
FROM
    tnames
WHERE
    fecha > '2014%'
        AND nombre IN 
           (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                nombre 
            FROM
                tnames 
            WHERE fecha > '2014%' AND
                nombre NOT IN ('marco', 'pedro') # Añade esto a tu consulta
           ) 
GROUP BY nombre
```

También puedes hacerlo como comenta el colega Lixus en su comentario, usando el operador `!=` (diferente de) o el operador `<>` (**no** igual a)

```
SELECT 
    nombre, MIN(fecha) desde, MAX(fecha) hasta
FROM
    tnames
WHERE
    fecha > '2014%'
        AND nombre IN 
           (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                nombre 
            FROM
                tnames 
            WHERE fecha > '2014%' AND
                nombre != 'marco' AND nombre != 'pedro' # Añade esto a tu consulta
                # nombre <> 'marco' AND nombre <> 'pedro'
           ) 
GROUP BY nombre
```